# One card is dealt to each of the 6 players. What are the odds of having a game where nobody has a trump card vs only one person having a trump card?

Tags: probability, card-games

The trump is picked last by picking one card from the remaining deck. A player has a trump card if it's of the same type as the trump card (ex. picked trump is 2 of clubs, player has 10 of clubs).

What are the odds nobody has a trump versus only one player has a trump and how do you calculate it?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to add the number of cards and number of players

Comment: @Bernd Number of cards would always be $52$. And each player is dealt with $1$ card. Though we need to know the number of players in the game.

Comment: @lsp indeed sorry I forgot to add the number of players. Updated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ No body having a trump:
$$4*39P_6$$
Logic: Assuming one of the $4$ types a trump, the number ways in which $6$ players can get a card which is not a trump is : $39*38*37*36*35*34$. This is because since the trump is fixed, you have to now select cards from a set of only $52-13=39$ cards. Also number number of ways of selecting trump is $4$.

$2.$ Exactly one player having a trump:
$$4*13*39P_5$$
Logic: Assuming one of the $4$ players has got a trump, the number of ways that can happen is $4*13$. So the other players should get non trumps which can be done in $39*38*37*36*35$ ways.

Comment: I am assuming those are matrices. Could you please explain where the numbers come from and how you have reached that formula? Thank you

Comment: As to number 1: I can see the 39 = 52 - 13 as the number of cards that are not of my kind. But this depends on the cards of the others - there might be and probably will be - less

Comment: Those are binomial coefficients 39! / ((39-4)! 4!)

Comment: @Bernd Yes. changed from $12$ to $13$.

Comment: Many thanks lsp and Bernd.

Comment: I think the 4 has to be omitted, if you want to calculate the odds. Because one card will for sure be trump and it doesn't matter which type it is

Comment: @Zadirion: is your question really answered - I would really like to see a probability somewhere, e.g. the probability that no person has a trump

Comment: I think he just needed to find the possibilities,which is the difficult part. He can easily calculate the total possibilities there by the probability.

Comment: See my answer below - I'm not sure what you mean by P6 (maybe 6! ?)

Comment: It is not $P6$, it is $39P_6$ ! Which means $39*38*37*36*35*34$ which is nothing but the numerator in your answer mentioned below.

Comment: Ok thank you. How do you make the index in the comments (like your 6)?

Comment: You can see how I did it by clicking on the edit option below my answer.Difficult to explain it here.

Comment: Thanks - I know how I can see it in the answer. But that didn't work in the comment. so I figured it's different in the comment ... which amazed me.

Comment: No. It works the same in comment as well. Try it out again.

Answer (score 2):

I would think, the probability for nobody having a trump is just:

39/51 * 38/50 * 37/49 * 36/48 * 35/47 * 34/46

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Can be interpreted either way:
- first player has to choose from one of the 39 non-trump cards, out of 51 cards (the 52nd is the trump), second from 38 out of 50 and so on.
or
- total number of games where nobody has a trump (39 * 38 * 37 * 36 * 35 * 34) out of/divided by total number of games with a trump card (51 * 50 * 49 * 48 * 47 * 46)

Thank you both for the great answers.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is 39/52*38/51*37/50*36/49*35/48*34/47
the reasoning is that probability for the first player to not get trump card is 39(no of non trump cards)/52(total no of cards) 
the probability for the second player to not get trump card is 38(remaining no of non trump cards)/51(total no of non trump cards)
and so on
and lastly all the probabilities are multiplied.

Comment: Remember that one card has been removed (the trump card) - therefore all your denominators are 1 to high. for the first card for the players there are only 51 left, for the second 50 and so on